# st_linemerge unless property changes

Tags: postgis, union

My question is as follows:

Given a LineShape as below, merge all elements UNLESS:

- Node of degree 3 or higher is present
- maxspeedkph property is different (50kmph -> 30kmph for example)

however when i group my links or union my links i either have no merging happening (input geom is used as grouping condition) or the resulting segments are too coarse (only max-speed grouping)

Example Network visually in QGIS:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULvGp.png

- White Nodes = Points that should be the endpoints after merging
- Red Crosses = Itermediate points that should be removed by the linemerging process
- Colors: Final resulting segments should be based on these nodes

[![QGIS visual representation of the desired result][1]][1]

Example Dataset (selection GIS CSV export)
public.nwb_uitsnede

```
"gid","beginnodeid","endnodeid","maxspeedkph","geom"
643981,"2106485","122102","130","0102000020E610000002000000C05AB56B428A1A40A7CB6262F3994A4088B9A46ABB891A40FCDEA63FFB994A40"
6904867,"1272255","5847515","130","0102000020E61000000300000060764F1E168A1A40024BAE62F1994A4026DF6C73638A1A403F19E3C3EC994A400ABFD4CF9B8A1A402F1686C8E9994A40"
6904877,"1272260","5847520","100","0102000020E6100000020000008481E7DEC3851A4087E123624A9A4A40F5F3A62215861A4028F04E3E3D9A4A40"
6904878,"5847520","5847521","100","0102000020E610000009000000F5F3A62215861A4028F04E3E3D9A4A4039D0436D1B861A40BD6DA6423C9A4A405B5B785E2A861A40DDEEE53E399A4A40344DD87E32861A40F67EA31D379A4A4050FEEE1D35861A409D9B36E3349A4A404A41B79734861A40AA7D3A1E339A4A409A7ADD2230861A4087DBA161319A4A40569E40D829861A40598B4F01309A4A402E73BA2C26861A4011DF89592F9A4A40"
6904879,"5847521","5847522","100","0102000020E61000000A0000002E73BA2C26861A4011DF89592F9A4A406D75392520861A40656D533C2E9A4A40016E162F16861A40780C8FFD2C9A4A4061C1FD8007861A4049BC3C9D2B9A4A40B1DD3D40F7851A405B5B785E2A9A4A4056F0DB10E3851A406EFAB31F299A4A4056B60F79CB851A4003780B24289A4A4051BF0B5BB3851A40BCCB457C279A4A40A1BE654E97851A40878A71FE269A4A40FC71FBE593851A40B60E0EF6269A4A40"
6904880,"5847522","5847523","100","0102000020E610000009000000FC71FBE593851A40B60E0EF6269A4A40132C0E677E851A40459BE3DC269A4A406EA5D76663851A40878A71FE269A4A4052BAF42F49851A40BCCB457C279A4A4024986A662D851A4003780B24289A4A40FD32182312851A40F1D8CF62299A4A404C4F58E201851A405B5B785E2A9A4A40198D7C5EF1841A4049BC3C9D2B9A4A404D158C4AEA841A403160C9552C9A4A40"
6904881,"5847523","5847524","100","0102000020E6100000050000004D158C4AEA841A403160C9552C9A4A405E2F4D11E0841A403CDA38622D9A4A40302AA913D0841A40E25AED612F9A4A4003250516C0841A40FE0B0401329A4A4047AAEFFCA2841A407138F3AB399A4A40"
7059386,"5942369","5942370","130","0102000020E610000003000000B8921D1B81881A40369204E10A9A4A40AC00DF6DDE881A404B0169FF039A4A4023BC3D0801891A40F31DFCC4019A4A40"
7059387,"5942370","5942371","130","0102000020E61000000300000023BC3D0801891A40F31DFCC4019A4A40287E8CB96B891A40098D60E3FA994A40611A868F88891A4027DA5548F9994A40"
7059388,"5942371","1272255","130","0102000020E610000002000000611A868F88891A4027DA5548F9994A4060764F1E168A1A40024BAE62F1994A40"
7059389,"1272260","5942372","100","0102000020E6100000020000008481E7DEC3851A4087E123624A9A4A401D59F96530861A405740A19E3E9A4A40"
7059390,"5942372","5942373","100","0102000020E6100000030000001D59F96530861A405740A19E3E9A4A40A52E19C748861A403B8F8AFF3B9A4A40603AADDBA0861A40DA01D715339A4A40"
7059391,"5942373","1298024","100","0102000020E610000003000000603AADDBA0861A40DA01D715339A4A4011018750A5861A40753C66A0329A4A407C0DC17119871A40C2887D02289A4A40"
7059392,"1298025","5942374","130","0102000020E6100000050000005C7347FFCB851A4009185DDE1C9A4A4001FA7DFFE6851A4057B5A4A31C9A4A407E8FFAEB15861A400F09DFFB1B9A4A40397EA83462861A40286552431B9A4A40F4F8BD4D7F861A4034130CE71A9A4A40"
7059393,"5942374","5942375","130","0102000020E610000005000000F4F8BD4D7F861A4034130CE71A9A4A40A5164A26A7861A402E56D4601A9A4A40711FB935E9861A4082E49D43199A4A406519E25817871A4047E6913F189A4A40E27492AD2E871A40003ACC97179A4A40"
7059394,"1298024","5942367","130","0102000020E6100000020000007C0DC17119871A40C2887D02289A4A406AF816D68D871A4056815A0C1E9A4A40"
7059395,"5942367","5942368","130","0102000020E6100000030000006AF816D68D871A4056815A0C1E9A4A40DB4DF04DD3871A4006F7031E189A4A40F2B5679604881A40FCE42840149A4A40"
7059396,"5942368","5942369","130","0102000020E610000003000000F2B5679604881A40FCE42840149A4A405857056A31881A40E62494BE109A4A40B8921D1B81881A40369204E10A9A4A40"
7059397,"5942375","5942376","130","0102000020E610000006000000E27492AD2E871A40003ACC97179A4A40107A36AB3E871A409B745B22179A4A408CF2CCCB61871A401E87C1FC159A4A40D0251C7A8B871A407EC34483149A4A40E78D93C2BC871A4097530262129A4A40B9DFA128D0871A409E44847F119A4A40"
7059398,"5942379","1272255","130","0102000020E610000003000000B6F3FDD478891A40DA70581AF8994A4061545227A0891A40056C0723F6994A4060764F1E168A1A40024BAE62F1994A40"
7059406,"5942376","5942377","130","0102000020E610000006000000B9DFA128D0871A409E44847F119A4A40F838D384ED871A406FF4311F109A4A4086E8103812881A40C9737D1F0E9A4A40919C4CDC2A881A409A232BBF0C9A4A40027E8D2441881A402AE44A3D0B9A4A40520E661360881A4055DFF945099A4A40"
7059407,"5942377","5942378","130","0102000020E610000004000000520E661360881A4055DFF945099A4A404CA8E0F082881A402C802903079A4A40D9E89C9FE2881A40B81FF0C0009A4A401EC539EAE8881A40F451465C009A4A40"
7059408,"5942378","5942379","130","0102000020E6100000030000001EC539EAE8881A40F451465C009A4A402387889B53891A400F7EE200FA994A40B6F3FDD478891A40DA70581AF8994A40"
7433774,"122102","6152806","130","0102000020E61000000200000088B9A46ABB891A40FCDEA63FFB994A4034677DCA31891A40691A14CD039A4A40"
7433775,"6152806","6152807","130","0102000020E61000000400000034677DCA31891A40691A14CD039A4A40782634492C891A408DF0F620049A4A4035289A07B0881A40DC12B9E00C9A4A4029AE2AFBAE881A407C0A80F10C9A4A40"
7433776,"6152807","6152808","130","0102000020E61000000300000029AE2AFBAE881A407C0A80F10C9A4A409C50888043881A403126FDBD149A4A40BE840A0E2F881A40425DA450169A4A40"
7433777,"6152808","6152809","130","0102000020E610000003000000BE840A0E2F881A40425DA450169A4A40588CBAD6DE871A4015C616821C9A4A4014596B28B5871A409CF9D51C209A4A40"
7433778,"6152809","1368360","130","0102000020E61000000200000014596B28B5871A409CF9D51C209A4A409ED2C1FA3F871A401A6CEA3C2A9A4A40"
7433779,"122102","6152810","130","0102000020E61000000300000088B9A46ABB891A40FCDEA63FFB994A4078B7B24467891A405EA0A4C0029A4A4017D34CF73A891A403271AB20069A4A40"
7433780,"6152810","6152811","130","0102000020E61000000400000017D34CF73A891A403271AB20069A4A405C1E6B4606891A407E7214200A9A4A4007B47405DB881A409432A9A10D9A4A40F6251B0FB6881A40452DCDAD109A4A40"
7433781,"6152811","6152812","130","0102000020E610000007000000F6251B0FB6881A40452DCDAD109A4A402F6B6281AF881A401B66683C119A4A402A745E6397881A4085B4C6A0139A4A403B71395E81881A4060764F1E169A4A406362F3716D881A403B38D89B189A4A401F4C8A8F4F881A4009185DDE1C9A4A40198F52094F881A40AA0F24EF1C9A4A40"
7433782,"6152812","6152813","130","0102000020E610000005000000198F52094F881A40AA0F24EF1C9A4A40B32781CD39881A40960854FF209A4A400344C18C29881A4023F94A20259A4A400327DBC01D881A402D0B26FE289A4A40D53E1D8F19881A40919C4CDC2A9A4A40"
7433786,"6152813","1368361","130","0102000020E610000004000000D53E1D8F19881A40919C4CDC2A9A4A4036AFEAAC16881A40C0EC9E3C2C9A4A40030AF5F411881A408ECC237F309A4A407A6EA12B11881A401EDE7360399A4A40"
7433796,"1368360","6152814","100","0102000020E6100000040000009ED2C1FA3F871A401A6CEA3C2A9A4A40931E865627871A4001DC2C5E2C9A4A40F4C308E1D1861A4098DEFE5C349A4A40933655F7C8861A4091ED7C3F359A4A40"
7433797,"6152814","6152815","100","0102000020E610000002000000933655F7C8861A4091ED7C3F359A4A40C7B94DB857861A40FDC0559E409A4A40"
7433798,"6152815","1368362","100","0102000020E610000003000000C7B94DB857861A40FDC0559E409A4A407EC9C6832D861A40CBA0DAE0449A4A40CE716E13EE851A402C62D8614C9A4A40"
7433858,"1368361","6152866","130","0102000020E6100000050000007A6EA12B11881A401EDE7360399A4A40D064FF3C0D881A40ABCE6A813D9A4A40369204E10A881A404A5E9D63409A4A407A51BB5F05881A405B61FA5E439A4A406FD74B5304881A404EB340BB439A4A40"
7433862,"6152866","6152867","130","0102000020E6100000050000006FD74B5304881A404EB340BB439A4A40A25F5B3FFD871A40B8019F1F469A4A40252191B6F1871A405891D101499A4A400953944BE3871A40B63176C24B9A4A4091D10149D8871A40A94F72874D9A4A40"
7433872,"6152867","1368378","130","0102000020E61000000300000091D10149D8871A40A94F72874D9A4A40D0D38041D2871A4013D21A834E9A4A407B4CA4349B871A409E2633DE569A4A40"
7433967,"6152936","6152937","100","0102000020E610000008000000C0B4A84F72871A402A58E36C3A9A4A40F31FD26F5F871A401230BABC399A4A405FD0420246871A409BFF571D399A4A40931E865627871A40A7AD11C1389A4A40494BE5ED08871A40E99C9FE2389A4A4005357C0BEB861A401EDE7360399A4A408D96033DD4861A40D6FD63213A9A4A407C5F5CAAD2861A4047718E3A3A9A4A40"
7433968,"6152937","6152938","100","0102000020E6100000050000007C5F5CAAD2861A4047718E3A3A9A4A40889FFF1EBC861A40054EB6813B9A4A40BBD05CA791861A4063EE5A423E9A4A406C06B8205B861A40E43098BF429A4A40618C48145A861A4055A4C2D8429A4A40"
7433969,"6152938","1368362","100","0102000020E610000002000000618C48145A861A4055A4C2D8429A4A40CE716E13EE851A402C62D8614C9A4A40"
7433970,"1368362","1368402","100","0102000020E610000002000000CE716E13EE851A402C62D8614C9A4A40AC72A1F2AF851A4094145800539A4A40"
7433971,"1368403","1272260","100","0102000020E61000000200000046D1031F83851A40A7B393C1519A4A408481E7DEC3851A4087E123624A9A4A40"
7433973,"1303384","6152939","130","0102000020E610000004000000AE80423D7D841A408F1D54E23A9A4A40AED7F4A0A0841A4040FB9122329A4A40D61F6118B0841A401E8D43FD2E9A4A40A85489B2B7841A40302C7FBE2D9A4A40"
7433974,"6152939","6152940","130","0102000020E610000006000000A85489B2B7841A40302C7FBE2D9A4A40300DC347C4841A408AABCABE2B9A4A401F10E84CDA841A402D0B26FE289A4A4091F12895F0841A40459BE3DC269A4A4041F2CEA10C851A40EDB776A2249A4A40695721E527851A409B9141EE229A4A40"
7433975,"6152940","1298025","130","0102000020E610000007000000695721E527851A409B9141EE229A4A40F1F274AE28851A40FA997ADD229A4A405D177E703E851A400D39B69E219A4A40240C03965C851A409CF9D51C209A4A400D6FD6E07D851A40AF9811DE1E9A4A40C3499A3FA6851A40C1374D9F1D9A4A405C7347FFCB851A4009185DDE1C9A4A40"
7433976,"1368401","6152934","100","0102000020E6100000040000005FED28CE51871A40AEF545425B9A4A40481630815B871A40B4E6C75F5A9A4A40BF28417FA1871A4078634161509A4A40C5E57805A2871A40D76B7A50509A4A40"
7433977,"6152934","6152935","100","0102000020E610000007000000C5E57805A2871A40D76B7A50509A4A40B4E89D0AB8871A4020B41EBE4C9A4A40BF7FF3E2C4871A4045F295404A9A4A40863AAC70CB871A40E1606F62489A4A4097715303CD871A40EE42739D469A4A40149337C0CC871A400C906802459A4A40863AAC70CB871A40965F0663449A4A40"
7433978,"6152935","6152936","100","0102000020E610000009000000863AAC70CB871A40965F0663449A4A406A8995D1C8871A40D882DE1B439A4A40AE484C50C3871A40F6CFD380419A4A40BF620D17B9871A4003B2D7BB3F9A4A4026732CEFAA871A40E00F3FFF3D9A4A408109DCBA9B871A40F3AE7AC03C9A4A403D1059A489871A40054EB6813B9A4A405987A3AB74871A40CA4FAA7D3A9A4A40C0B4A84F72871A402A58E36C3A9A4A40"
8417819,"1368378","1368404","130","0102000020E6100000040000007B4CA4349B871A409E2633DE569A4A403196E99788871A4091442FA3589A4A407638BA4A77871A40EFE4D3635B9A4A4053CA6B2574871A40661536035C9A4A40"
8493994,"1368378","1582529","130","0102000020E6100000040000007B4CA4349B871A409E2633DE569A4A404E64E60297871A40859675FF589A4A40096B63EC84871A40661536035C9A4A40EDB94C4D82871A408FA850DD5C9A4A40"
```

nwb_samenvoegen.nwb_wegvakken_propageren_nodes:

```
    -- All Nodes to be Merged (same speed, degree2)
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS propageren.nwb_wegvakken_propageren_nodes;
    CREATE TABLE propageren.nwb_wegvakken_propageren_nodes AS
    WITH node_nummers AS(
        SELECT  
                beginnodeid AS nodenummer, 
                maxspeedkph,
                ST_STARTPOINT(geom) point_geom
        FROM public.nwb_uitsnede
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  
                endnodeid AS nodenummer,
                maxspeedkph,
                ST_ENDPOINT(geom) point_geom
        FROM public.nwb_uitsnede
    ),
    met_max_snelh AS (
        SELECT 
            nodenummer, 
            maxspeedkph,
            count(*) aantal, 
            ST_CENTROID(ST_UNION(point_geom)) point_geom 
        FROM node_nummers
        GROUP BY nodenummer, maxspeedkph
    ),
    statistieken AS (
        SELECT 
            nodenummer, 
            sum(aantal) totaal_aantal, 
            count(*) aantal_max_snelh,
            ST_CENTROID(ST_UNION(point_geom)) point_geom 
        FROM met_max_snelh  
        GROUP BY nodenummer
    ) 
    SELECT nodenummer, point_geom
    FROM statistieken
    WHERE totaal_aantal = 2 AND aantal_max_snelh = 1;
```

Example Query Used:

```
    SELECT 
        maxspeedkph, 
        st_linemerge(ST_UNION(geom))
    FROM public.nwb_uitsnede
    LEFT JOIN nwb_samenvoegen.nwb_wegvakken_propageren_nodes ON beginnodeid = nodenummer OR endnodeid = nodenummer
    WHERE nodenummer > -1
    GROUP BY maxspeedkph,geom;
```

resulted in too many small segments (crosses didnt get merged)

```
    SELECT 
        maxspeedkph, 
        st_linemerge(ST_UNION(geom))
    FROM public.nwb_uitsnede
    LEFT JOIN nwb_samenvoegen.nwb_wegvakken_propageren_nodes ON beginnodeid = nodenummer OR endnodeid = nodenummer
    WHERE nodenummer > -1
    GROUP BY maxspeedkph
```

resulted in too few segments (everything gets merged with same speed
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULvGp.png